# select query in sql server 2008

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
create table tblchildinfo
  (id int, name varchar(50), 
   pickuppointid int, dropdownpointid int)
```

and

```
create table tblpoint(pointid int, PointName varchar(50))
```

So I have primary table tblpoint and child table as tblchildinfo and i want to write a statement such that i will get child id, child name, pickuppointID, pickuppointName, dropdownpointId & dropdownpoint name

Using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.id, c.name, p.name, p.pointid, p2.pointid, p2.name
from tblchildinfo c
join tblpoint p on c.pickuppointid = p.pointid
join tblpoint p2 on c.dropdownpointid = p2.pointid
where <Insert where clause>
```

should do you.

Comment: I want pickupPointName And PickUpPointId too
:)

Comment: I've added that in. You just add a selector for each of the fields you want. The join ensures that fields from both tables are available.

Comment: I appreciate ur help buddy...but i want dropdownpoint name too...
ie out put with two different name and two diffrent Ids
tnx

Comment: I've editted it for you. It works, but i'm not sure it's good practice to use joins like that :)

Comment: You might need left joins on both of those if you can't guarantee that the parent record will have both

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional query over two tables or use a LEFT JOIN on tblpoint. Btw, for readability i sugguest using unserscores for 'multi-word-name' tables, such as tbl_child_info and tbl_point.

Comment: I appreciate ur help buddy...but i want dropdownpoint name too... ie out put with two different name and two diffrent Ids tnx

Comment: While the tbl prefix is useless, the use of under_scores vs. CamelCase for readability is totally subjective.  I prefer CamelCase in table names, but that is because I find them easier to read and type than underscores.  YMMV.